# Get html code as string from iframe in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

In my project I am loading iframe where's some svg code which I need to get in my script as string. Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Edge but I have some problems in IE 11.

HTML:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
 <iframe id="my-iframe">
  ...
  <svg id="my-svg"></svg>
  ...
 </iframe>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var iframe = $("#my-iframe");
var svg = iframe.contents().find("#my-svg");
var svgText = $(svg[0]).html();
```

This solution is not working in IE 11 because in console I got svgText as `undefined`, I think the problem is here: `var svgText = $(svg[0]).html()` but what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try: var svgText = svg.html(); (haven't tried it).

Comment: Same effect, it's working on chrome and other browser but not in IE 11

Comment: Probably some kind of security. Is the iframe showing content from same origin?

Comment: Yes, it's same origin

Comment: What is going to be inside your svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I had to use `XMLSerializer`

Solution:

```
var iframe = $("#my-iframe");
var svg = iframe.contents().find("#my-svg");
var svgText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg[0]);
```

Comment: Beat me to it...`var svgText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString($("#my-iframe").contents().find("#my-svg")[0]);` Glad you solved it

Comment: @pawel, I can see that you had solved the issue. I suggest you to mark your solution as an answer for this thread can help other members in future.